# how to add 'Time' as a column with 2 minutes time difference in mysql

Tags: mysql

I want to add 'Time' as a column and for every time it should display after 2 minute's time with the date and time difference should be of 2 minutes,it should start with 00:00:00 till 12:00:00 for a day.I am getting date but not time. 
Example:

```
         Date            time
         01/01/2000     00:02:00
         01/01/2000     00:04:24
         01/01/2000     00:06:56
             till
         02/01/2000     12:00:00
```

Please help me for this.

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to accomplish? Are you adding rows by hand to the database? What step is failing in what you are trying to do?

Comment: No i dont want to edit it manually is there any way for time to increment by 2 mins so that i can get timestamp with 2 mins difference with date.

Comment: show sample data that you have now, a query that uses it currently, and output from that query noting what you want different.  There are about three different things I think you could mean and you aren't going to be clear about what you want without an example.

Comment: date  01/01/2000  time 00:02:12 next time should be like 00:04:12 again in next 00:06:34

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL TO Get DATE AND TIME

SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') DATEONLY, 
       DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY;

SQL TO ADD 2 minutes IN TIME

```
   SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d') DATEONLY, 
  DATE_FORMAT( DATE_ADD(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 MINUTE),'%H:%i:%s') TIMEONLY;
```

Comment: Thanx Trushna bt i dont want it for current date i want this for entered date

Answer (score 0):

Need more information....could you please share a dummy data. To add time to datestamp...you simply have to use "addtime". For example, addtime(time,"00:02:00"), this adds two minutes to the datestamp "time" variable.

Comment: date  01/01/2000  time 00:02:12 next time should be like 00:04:12 again in next 00:06:34 i just wanted to create dummy test data from 01/01/2000 to 30/05/2016 in which date will be there and time but for 1 day time has 720 records with the 2 mins difference .1 day= 24hrs ,24hrs * 60 mins=1440 mins , 1440/2= 720 mins ,i want 720 records for a single day